# Calling overloaded operator function from struct pointer

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have the following struct in C++

```
struct Jam
{
    void operator()()
    {
        cout << "Test";
    }
};
```

And I am able to call the overloaded function like so:

```
Jam j;
j();
```

But I was wondering what the proper way to call the function from a pointer to the same struct. For example if I have:

```
Jam *j = new Jam;
j->();
```

I receive errors telling me it needs a function name. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest and clearest way is to dereference the pointer:

```
(*j)();
```

Alternatively, you can use the `->` syntax with the function's name (which is `operator()`):

```
j->operator()();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting; Will accept as soon as SO lets me.